# Radio button does not call setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a simple method in a react program that is supposed to change a state and update a specified value for a Radio button:

The state :

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   checked: [],
   expanded: [],
   keyword: "",
   protocol:"",
   time:""
   };
  }
   .
   . 
   .
  }
```

the method :

```
  handleProtocolChange = (e, {value}) =>this.setState({protocol: 
     value })
 handleTimeChange =  (e, {value}) =>this.setState({time: value })
```

The radio element:

```
 return (
  <Form>
  <Form.Field>
  <h1 className="rct-icon-half-check2">Selected Time: <b>{this.state.time}</b></h1>
  </Form.Field>
  <Form.Field>
    <Radio
      label='Last 30 minutes'
      name='radioGroup'
      value='Last 30 minutes'
      checked={this.state.time === "Last 30 minutes"}
      onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
    />
  </Form.Field>
  <Form.Field>
    <Radio
      label='Last Hour'
      name='radioGroup'
      value='Last Hour'
      checked={this.state.time === "Last Hour"}
      onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
    />
  </Form.Field>
  <Form.Field>
    <Radio
      label='Last 8 Hours'
      name='radioGroup'
      value='Last 8 Hours'
      checked={this.state.time === "Last 8 Hours"}
      onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
    />
  </Form.Field>
  <Form.Field>
    <Radio
      label='Last 24 Hours'
      name='radioGroup'
      value='Last 24 Hours'
      checked={this.state.time === "Last 24 Hours"}
      onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
    />
  </Form.Field>

</Form>

)
```

However, whenever the radio button is pressed, the setState is never called. The state changes but the checked element for the button is never seen: here are images of the before and after. Notice in the inspection tools how the state is changing but the button isn't shown:

I would appreciate any help detecting the issue

[before pressing radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpDfS.png)

[after pressing the radio button..state change is shown in inspector,yet no sign of change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXYuD.png)
I'm sorry for mistaken you too early, the component i was talking about was the set time state. Here is the updated product the same issue occurs.

Comment: The state shown to be changing in your screenshots is the `time` value, but the code you've pasted doesn't show the time change handler being used. Also there's a possible typo - `chandleTimeChange` .

Answer (score 0):

Issues in your code, first of all you can simplify your functions,

```
handleProtocolChange = (e) => this.setState({protocol: e.target.value })
chandleTimeChange =  (e) => this.setState({time: e.target.value }) // make sure `chandleTimeChange` is not a typo
```

You have conflicted code here,

```
<h1 className="rct-icon-half-check2">Selected protocol: <b>{this.state.protocol}</b></h1>
```

And

```
<Radio
   label='Modbus'
   name='radioGroup'
   value='Modbus'
   checked={this.props.protocol === "Modbus"}
   onChange={(this.handleProtocolChange)}
/>
```

At one place you are using `this.state.protocol` and another place you are using `this.props.protocol`, make sure this is not a typo.